# How to perform a click with normal speed using Selenium .NET Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I intend to use a webshop with the Selenium Webdriver to put items in the cart.

When I *manually* use the shop and click the basket icon (it is actually a `div` with an `i` tag), I can see the following code sent to the API:

[image]

I use the following code to find the `div` element with Selenium and click it:

```
var basket = parentTag.FindElement(By.ClassName("basket"));
if (basket != null)
{
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.MoveToElement(basket).Build().Perform();  
  await Task.Delay(1000);                    
  actions.Click(basket).Build().Perform();
}
```

Unfortunately, using the click I get the following network output and the basket remains empty:

[image]

As the cart remains empty I guess the Selenium click is *too quick* or somehow 'breaks' the normal behavior.

What could I do to better simulate a manual click?

Answer (score 0):

First try to put breakpoints and analyze all operations, because there might be some extra pop-up or something like that. Once you are sure that everything is done correctly, you can put a

```
Thread.sleep(2000); // Time in ms
```

between specific actions. Waiting for a given element to render is an even better solution (I learned this from [Ran Adler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2447599/ran-adler) sometime in the past):

```
public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));

    return findElement(driver, selector);
}
```